# connect to mysql

Tags: miktex, database

I try to run `nlatexdb` to connect to `mysql`.
I'm using Miktex on Windows 7 with TexnicCenter
In MySql I have a database called 'world'. 
In 'world' there is a table called 'city'.
The table 'city' consists of four rows:
'ID', 'Name', 'CountryCode', 'District', 'Population'.

Using `LaTeX` I try to display the date in this table.

My `.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\texdbconnectionnet{MySql.Data.MySqlClient}
{Database=world; Uid=root; Pwd=XXXXX;}

\texdbdef{##stadt}{select ID, Name, CountryCode, District, Population from world.city}
{##ID, ##Name, ##CountryCode, ##District, ##Population}



\texdbfor{##stadt}{
Die Stadt ##Name hat die ID-Nummer ##ID und den Code ##CountryCode. 
}

\end{document}
```

When I run nlatexdb using the console (nlatexdb -p test.tex) I get the
error message: 
Host 'XXXXX' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

I hope you can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here.
Is the Uid correct? I triet different Uid's but always get the same message.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Are you able to connect using `mysql` explicitly (outside of TeX and `nlatexdb`)? For example, if you run `mysql -u root -p --database=world` from the console do you get the same error? If you do, then you might be better off asking on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I could connect outside TeX.

After several more attempts to get it to run it turns out I forgot to declare the server.

Using

```
\texdbconnectionnet{MySql.Data.MySqlClient}{Server=localhost;Database=sakila; User=Manuel;Password=XXXXXX;}
```

I could connect to the locally installed MySQL and run nlatexdb.