# MongoDB to math Latex

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, unicode-math, mathtools, mathjax

I am working on math quiz application and I want to store the math equations in to database.How to save math equations into mongodb database ?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) I don't really see how this is related to LaTeX and friends.

Comment: You could simply save the LaTeX code and let the client render or you could (very bad) pre-render the images and save them to db. So it's actually dependent on your use case and whether you're really after LaTeX or after something like MathJax (which is not LaTeX).

Comment: Although the use case here, as @TeXnician said, seems to be an online application and therefore off-topic, I do like the idea of the question, similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180018/luatex-context-connect-to-sql-server, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169878/connect-to-mysql, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-database-to-latex-to-produce-data-driven-documents/25814, which usually do not get a lot of responses from the community, or one line 'you might try this general approach/tool'-responses, even though being on-topic.